# Disable Errorlogs/Dumps - Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, windows, server, windows-server-2008-r2, jvm-hotspot

on one of my servers iam getting a java error. That error creates a lot of .log and .mdmp files which fill up the server. The dumps are located on c:windows and that causes the system to create alerts when c is low on disk space.

I cant change the Javaversion because exactly that version is needed by an important software which runs on that system and anyway everything is working fine even with that java error.

Is there any way to disable those dumpfiles and logs or redirect them to be saved on d:?

btw, here is one of those logfiles:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6fae6d27, pid=4244, tid=17956
#
# JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x6d27]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\WINDOWS\system32\hs_err_pid4244.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x4d536400):  JavaThread "Thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=17956, stack(0x4d1c0000,0x4d2c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000164

Registers:
EAX=0x0000dead, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x4d3c4400, EDX=0x0000dead
ESP=0x4d2bfa80, EBP=0x4d2bfa84, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x6fae6d27, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x4d2bfa80)
0x4d2bfa80:   005fe798 4d2bfaa0 6fb9072a 00000000
0x4d2bfa90:   00000006 005fe798 00000000 005fe798
0x4d2bfaa0:   00000001 0111a048 4d3c4528 4c278000
0x4d2bfab0:   005fe798 ffffffff 4d3c0330 00000036
0x4d2bfac0:   0111bf38 00000001 0111c1d8 4d536400
0x4d2bfad0:   00000000 4d2bfb38 04dffa18 0111d0a1
0x4d2bfae0:   4d3c0330 00000001 00000001 0111f410
0x4d2bfaf0:   04dffa18 011d2a6a 00000001 01c4aee4 

Instructions: (pc=0x6fae6d27)
0x6fae6d07:   c4 04 89 96 64 01 00 00 5e 5d c3 8b 45 10 89 86
0x6fae6d17:   64 01 00 00 5e 5d c3 cc cc 55 8b ec 56 8b 75 08
0x6fae6d27:   c7 86 64 01 00 00 05 00 00 00 83 3d 50 e3 fa 6f
0x6fae6d37:   01 7e 19 80 3d e9 dc fa 6f 00 74 07 f0 83 04 24 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x0000dead is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x4d3c4400 is an unknown value
EDX=0x0000dead is an unknown value
ESP=0x4d2bfa80 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4d536400
EBP=0x4d2bfa84 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4d536400
ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x4d1c0000,0x4d2c0000],  sp=0x4d2bfa80,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x6d27]
V  [jvm.dll+0xb072a]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.ietsol.enterprise.EntClient.exitNow(I)V+0
j  com.ietsol.enterprise.EntAAGtwyHandler.run()V+83
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x4d536400 JavaThread "Thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=17956, stack(0x4d1c0000,0x4d2c0000)]
  0x4d494800 JavaThread "Thread-0" [_thread_in_native, id=13020, stack(0x4d920000,0x4da20000)]
  0x4c2e2400 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13304, stack(0x4cd30000,0x4ce30000)]
  0x4c2dfc00 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11192, stack(0x4d0a0000,0x4d1a0000)]
  0x4c2cf400 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16240, stack(0x4ce90000,0x4cf90000)]
  0x4c2c6400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18248, stack(0x4cc20000,0x4cd20000)]
  0x4c271c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10336, stack(0x4c5d0000,0x4c6d0000)]
  0x4c26cc00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14020, stack(0x4bff0000,0x4c0f0000)]
  0x0056c800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=7584, stack(0x001d0000,0x002d0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00c4d400 VMThread [stack: 0x4c420000,0x4c520000] [id=11088]
  0x4c2e3000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x4d2c0000,0x4d3c0000] [id=3484]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 8320K, used 5667K [0x336f0000, 0x34180000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8256K, 68% used [0x336f0000,0x33c6cf48,0x33f00000)
  from space 64K, 75% used [0x33f20000,0x33f2c000,0x33f30000)
  to   space 1280K, 0% used [0x34040000,0x34040000,0x34180000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7173K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x093415f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3663K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd3e38,0x05c40000)

Card table byte_map: [0x48c40000,0x48e70000] byte_map_base: 0x48c19e00

Polling page: 0x00170000

Code Cache  [0x01c40000, 0x01e80000, 0x04c40000)
 total_blobs=352 nmethods=211 adapters=93 free_code_cache=48314Kb largest_free_block=49436096

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 69279.567 Thread 0x4c2cf400  211             java.lang.ref.SoftReference::get (29 bytes)
Event: 69279.568 Thread 0x4c2cf400 nmethod 211 0x01ce4108 code [0x01ce4200, 0x01ce4270]
Event: 71139.400 Thread 0x4c2dfc00  212   !         java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl::isConnectionReset (31 bytes)
Event: 71139.402 Thread 0x4c2dfc00 nmethod 212 0x01ce0408 code [0x01ce0500, 0x01ce06b0]
Event: 74679.318 Thread 0x4c2cf400  213             sun.util.calendar.Gregorian::newCalendarDate (9 bytes)
Event: 74679.320 Thread 0x4c2cf400 nmethod 213 0x01c8f908 code [0x01c8fa00, 0x01c8fb10]
Event: 75039.158 Thread 0x4c2dfc00  214             java.net.SocketInputStream::read (15 bytes)
Event: 75039.158 Thread 0x4c2cf400  215   !         java.net.SocketInputStream::read (290 bytes)
Event: 75039.184 Thread 0x4c2cf400 nmethod 215 0x01cf91c8 code [0x01cf9420, 0x01cfa428]
Event: 75039.199 Thread 0x4c2dfc00 nmethod 214 0x01cf6c08 code [0x01cf6e60, 0x01cf7e68]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 46910.252 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1089 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 10240K, used 8977K [0x336f0000, 0x34280000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8768K, 100% used [0x336f0000,0x33f80000,0x33f80000)
  from space 1472K, 14% used [0x34110000,0x34144640,0x34280000)
  to   space 1536K, 0% used [0x33f80000,0x33f80000,0x34100000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7109K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 43% used [0x08c40000,0x093315f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3660K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd33c8,0x05c40000)
Event: 46910.253 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1089 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 10304K, used 198K [0x336f0000, 0x34420000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8768K, 0% used [0x336f0000,0x336f0000,0x33f80000)
  from space 1536K, 12% used [0x33f80000,0x33fb19c0,0x34100000)
  to   space 1472K, 0% used [0x342b0000,0x342b0000,0x34420000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7137K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x093385f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3660K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd33c8,0x05c40000)
}
Event: 49274.397 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1090 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 10304K, used 8966K [0x336f0000, 0x34420000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8768K, 100% used [0x336f0000,0x33f80000,0x33f80000)
  from space 1536K, 12% used [0x33f80000,0x33fb19c0,0x34100000)
  to   space 1472K, 0% used [0x342b0000,0x342b0000,0x34420000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7137K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x093385f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3660K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd33c8,0x05c40000)
Event: 49274.398 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1090 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 8704K, used 64K [0x336f0000, 0x342c0000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8640K, 0% used [0x336f0000,0x336f0000,0x33f60000)
  from space 64K, 100% used [0x342b0000,0x342c0000,0x342c0000)
  to   space 1472K, 0% used [0x33fe0000,0x33fe0000,0x34150000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7149K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x0933b5f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3660K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd33c8,0x05c40000)
}
Event: 51099.959 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1091 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 8704K, used 8704K [0x336f0000, 0x342c0000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8640K, 100% used [0x336f0000,0x33f60000,0x33f60000)
  from space 64K, 100% used [0x342b0000,0x342c0000,0x342c0000)
  to   space 1472K, 0% used [0x33fe0000,0x33fe0000,0x34150000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7149K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x0933b5f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3661K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd3688,0x05c40000)
Event: 51099.960 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1091 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 9984K, used 48K [0x336f0000, 0x342c0000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8512K, 0% used [0x336f0000,0x336f0000,0x33f40000)
  from space 1472K, 3% used [0x33fe0000,0x33fec000,0x34150000)
  to   space 1408K, 0% used [0x34160000,0x34160000,0x342c0000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7153K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x0933c5f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3661K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd3688,0x05c40000)
}
Event: 60699.402 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1092 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 9984K, used 8560K [0x336f0000, 0x342c0000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8512K, 100% used [0x336f0000,0x33f40000,0x33f40000)
  from space 1472K, 3% used [0x33fe0000,0x33fec000,0x34150000)
  to   space 1408K, 0% used [0x34160000,0x34160000,0x342c0000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7153K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x0933c5f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3661K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd3688,0x05c40000)
Event: 60699.403 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1092 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 8768K, used 64K [0x336f0000, 0x341c0000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8384K, 0% used [0x336f0000,0x336f0000,0x33f20000)
  from space 384K, 16% used [0x34160000,0x34170000,0x341c0000)
  to   space 1344K, 0% used [0x33f20000,0x33f20000,0x34070000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7161K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x0933e5f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3661K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd3688,0x05c40000)
}
Event: 70779.220 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1093 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 8768K, used 8448K [0x336f0000, 0x341c0000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8384K, 100% used [0x336f0000,0x33f20000,0x33f20000)
  from space 384K, 16% used [0x34160000,0x34170000,0x341c0000)
  to   space 1344K, 0% used [0x33f20000,0x33f20000,0x34070000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7161K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x0933e5f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3663K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd3e38,0x05c40000)
Event: 70779.221 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1093 (full 10):
 PSYoungGen      total 8320K, used 48K [0x336f0000, 0x34180000, 0x48c40000)
  eden space 8256K, 0% used [0x336f0000,0x336f0000,0x33f00000)
  from space 64K, 75% used [0x33f20000,0x33f2c000,0x33f30000)
  to   space 1280K, 0% used [0x34040000,0x34040000,0x34180000)
 ParOldGen       total 16192K, used 7173K [0x08c40000, 0x09c10000, 0x336f0000)
  object space 16192K, 44% used [0x08c40000,0x093415f8,0x09c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 3663K [0x04c40000, 0x05c40000, 0x08c40000)
  object space 16384K, 22% used [0x04c40000,0x04fd3e38,0x05c40000)
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 19574.358 Thread 0x4e7fec00 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0x01c89554
Event: 19752.307 Thread 0x4e7fec00 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x01cac7fc
Event: 20116.836 Thread 0x4e7fec00 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x01c8faa8
Event: 21099.564 Thread 0x4e7fec00 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x01cc59b0
Event: 25181.201 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x01caf678
Event: 27460.462 Thread 0x4e7fec00 Uncommon trap -28 fr.pc 0x01cdc3e0
Event: 28816.193 Thread 0x4d44cc00 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x01ca64e0
Event: 38413.449 Thread 0x4d4e9000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x01c8fd58
Event: 38732.959 Thread 0x4eafa000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x01c9da80
Event: 38732.959 Thread 0x4eafa000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x01cccd3c

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 75029.223 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Threw 0x33a6b1f8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 75329.216 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Threw 0x33aa9aa8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 75629.193 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Threw 0x33ae8498 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 75929.191 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Threw 0x33b26da0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 76229.161 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Threw 0x33b656f0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 76529.136 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Threw 0x33ba4058 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 76829.117 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Threw 0x33be2908 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 77129.098 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Threw 0x33c21220 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 77425.028 Thread 0x4d536400 Threw 0x33c6beb8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 77425.028 Thread 0x4d536400 Threw 0x33c6bff8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742

Events (10 events):
Event: 55074.408 Thread 0x4d4e8c00 Thread exited: 0x4d4e8c00
Event: 60699.402 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 60699.403 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 66459.696 loading class 0x4d4c9978
Event: 66459.696 loading class 0x4d4c9978 done
Event: 70779.220 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 70779.221 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 77382.116 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 77382.116 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 77382.116 Thread 0x4d3c4400 Thread exited: 0x4d3c4400


Dynamic libraries:
0x77090000 - 0x77210000     C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x754d0000 - 0x755e0000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x757e0000 - 0x75827000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x75390000 - 0x75490000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x74f00000 - 0x74f90000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x752f0000 - 0x752fa000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x75910000 - 0x759ad000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x74c80000 - 0x74d2c000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x75830000 - 0x758d0000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x75720000 - 0x75739000     C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x74f90000 - 0x75080000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x74bb0000 - 0x74c10000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74ba0000 - 0x74bac000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x74a90000 - 0x74a97000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x758d0000 - 0x75905000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x754c0000 - 0x754c6000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x73a80000 - 0x73ab2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x74c10000 - 0x74c15000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x72e90000 - 0x72f4f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCR100.dll
0x72980000 - 0x729ca000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
0x74c20000 - 0x74c80000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75220000 - 0x752ec000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x72900000 - 0x7297e000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
0x75780000 - 0x757d7000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x72a90000 - 0x72aa0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x72a80000 - 0x72a90000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\napinsp.dll
0x72d40000 - 0x72d7c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x72a30000 - 0x72a74000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x72a20000 - 0x72a28000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x759b0000 - 0x765fb000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x76930000 - 0x76a8c000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x732b0000 - 0x7344e000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
0x75640000 - 0x756cf000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x75080000 - 0x7521d000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75490000 - 0x754b7000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x76c70000 - 0x76c82000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x75300000 - 0x75383000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x6c090000 - 0x6c185000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\propsys.dll
0x73cb0000 - 0x73cb9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6bf10000 - 0x6bf16000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wship6.dll
0x72d30000 - 0x72d35000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x73de0000 - 0x73dfc000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x73dd0000 - 0x73dd7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x6c5d0000 - 0x6c608000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6c5c0000 - 0x6c5c6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6af40000 - 0x6af48000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\credssp.dll
0x5db20000 - 0x5dbaa000     C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Kerberos.DLL
0x72340000 - 0x72351000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\cryptdll.dll
0x75770000 - 0x7577c000     C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
0x71ca0000 - 0x7233d000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
0x72820000 - 0x728f7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
0x70c30000 - 0x71c9b000     C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\d1265d6159ea876f9d63ea4c1361b587\mscorlib.ni.dll
0x727a0000 - 0x7281d000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
0x725e0000 - 0x725f2000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
0x70290000 - 0x70c2d000     C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d18e2115a3270f89663fce831547f534\System.ni.dll
0x6f3e0000 - 0x6f573000     C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\53d0b6fa2fc28f7d50f84999fc2a1bbf\System.Drawing.ni.dll
0x6ca00000 - 0x6caeb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DBGHELP.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xrs 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
USERNAME=serviceuser
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 12582456k(3857676k free), swap 16770812k(8354748k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.7-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_17-b02), built on Mar  1 2013 05:01:01 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Sat Aug 15 00:00:46 2015
elapsed time: 77425 seconds
```

Thanks

Comment: Review this method: `com.ietsol.enterprise.EntClient.exitNow(I)`

Comment: These logs are very helpful. They indicate something seriously went wrong with your JVM and that's why it died. Are you sure you want to disable it? It is absolutely not recommended.

Comment: Well, we restart our software every night which could cause that error somehow, I didnt figure out if thats the reason or not. Somedays I get the error logs, somedays not, some nights 1-3 dumps... They are not necessary because like I said, everything works fine. In some months we update the software including java and then this problem might be gone anyway but for now its just a waste of space on the disk.